# Can I just style decimals of a number in Angular?

Tags: css, angularjs

I am trying to style just the decimals to look just like this:

[image]

Didn't had success, I guess that I need to make my own filter, tried but didn't had success either, I guess it is because I am using it inside a state.

Here the code I am using for the number:

```
<h2><sup>$</sup>{{salary | number:0}}<sub>.00</sub></h2>
```

Inside the **.app** iam using this scope:

$scope.salary = 9000;

Thing is, number can be whatever the user salary is, it get the number from an input, in other places I have more numbers with decimals too.

**Possible solutions:**

- Extract only the decimals from value and print them inside de
   tag.
- Use a filter to do this?

Comment: This seems like a good case for a directive, IMO.

Comment: Easiest way would be as you said to just split the integer values from the decimals. A filter wouldn't really help you here. A directive would probably be best but might be overkill. I'd ask myself how often you will see yourself encountering the same situation. If more than once then I'd go with the directive .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a directive that will split the amount and generate the proper HTML.  [For example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Em5SSeHBQBffHvQS8E1z?p=preview):

```
app.directive('salary', function(){
  return {
      restrict: 'E'
      , scope: {
          salary: '@'
      }
      , controller: controller
      , controllerAs: 'dvm'
      , bindToController: true
      , template: '<h2><sup>$</sup>{{ dvm.dollar }}<sub>.{{ dvm.cents }}</sub></h2>'
  };

  function controller(){
    var parts = parseFloat(this.salary).toFixed(2).split(/\./);
    this.dollar = parts[0];
    this.cents = parts[1];
  }
});
```

Comment: This seams to be very nice and just what I am looking for. Where shold I paste this code? I have the .state then views:{} inside views I have controller.

Do I paste it inside the controller?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to split out the number into it's decimal portion and the whole number portion:

```js
var number = 90000.99111;

console.log(number % 1);
```

Use this in your controller, and split your scope variable into an object:

```
 $scope.salary = {
    whole: salary,
    decimal: salary % 1
  }
```

**Protip:** Using an object like this is better than using two scope variables for performance

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but how can I use it in the view? salary:decimal?

Comment: You can use it as `salary.decimal`

Comment: Hello, I discover something in your scope: decimals are not correct, this is due to the fact that we are only moving the dot. Example if we have 34.56 with this solution the result will be 0.34, which is incorrect, it should be .56

I think I need to conver the result to stric, cut it, then return it back to value.